# Create Download Link PHP

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, download

I had a problem with my code . when I click the button to download the picture , it appears the code that I do not know, how to solve this ? what is wrong with my code ?

--> Download.php

```
if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
    $filename = $_GET['file'];
} else {
    $filename = NULL;
}


// define error message
$err = '<p style="color:#990000">Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable.</p>';

if (!$filename) {
    // if variable $filename is NULL or false display the message
    echo $err;
} else {
    // define the path to your download folder plus assign the file name
    $path = '../images/upload/lowongan_pekerjaan/'.$filename;
    // check that file exists and is readable
    if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
        // get the file size and send the http headers
        $size = filesize($path);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        // open the file in binary read-only mode
        // display the error message if file can't be opened
        $file = @fopen($path, 'rb');
        if ($file) {
            // stream the file and exit the script when complete
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo $err;
        }
    } else {
        echo $err;
    }
}
```

why show like this?
[My Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWFES.png)

whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you able to open the file in an image editor and resave it? I've had issues previously where the image has become corrupt.

Comment: Also check for any blank spaces at the end of any php files you include. blank lines can cause a problem with the download. As the blank lines count towards the length you specify so it never downloads the full image

Comment: stay same problem when I change to @thomas-b

this is my bursa_detail.php which has download lin button to access download.php

<a href="menu_alumni.php?a=download&file='.$basename_gambar.'" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Poster</a>

Comment: Have you already started outputting the template? @alfiyan28. If you want to make it download the image, no html or anything else can be output. The image output has to be the ONLY thing you echo out

Comment: hi all, 
I have successfully downloaded the image with the code above . but the problem now when the image has been downloaded in the open it says "windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged or is too large"

Comment: [[FIXED]] add ob_flush() after  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

Thanks ALL

Answer (score 1):

```
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

should be

```
    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```

or png or gif or whatever your file type is.. the browser does not know how to handle what you are sending it because application/octet-stream != an image type.

Comment: I gather he's trying to make it popup as a file download hence the octet stream content type. This forces people to click save file or open instead of opening directly in the browser window

Comment: Content-Disposition: attachment should accomplish that.  But i just tested using his code and it works.  So my guess is its bad in from $_GET['filename']

Comment: [[FIXED]] add ob_flush() after header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); Thanks ALL